# innerHTML with if/ese using javascript is closing the table tags before if statement

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing some output in form of a table to a div tag using JavaScript but I have to use if statement to avoid empty fields in the output. But when I view it in the browser the table tag is getting closed by browser before the if statement and its ignoring the td tags inside the if statement. what am I missing?

here is my JavaScript code:

```
qdetails.innerHTML = "<h4 style='font-size:24px;padding:5px 0;margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#000;'>Order Details</h4>";
qdetails.innerHTML +="<table style='border: 1px solid #ddd;width:100%;' cellpadding='6'><tr><td><strong>Apparel Color Selected:</strong> "+ document.getElementById('colorselected').value + "</td></tr>";
if(getAdultQty().howmany_adult_s != 0){
  qdetails.innerHTML +="<tr><td><strong>Adult Small:</strong> "+ getAdultQty().howmany_adult_s + "</td></tr>";  
}
qdetails.innerHTML +="</table>";
```

and HTML output:

```
<h4 style='font-size:24px;padding:5px 0;margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#000;'>Order Details</h4>
<table style='border: 1px solid #ddd;width:100%;' cellpadding='6'><tr><td><strong>Apparel Color Selected:</strong> Black</td></tr></table>
Adult Small: 20
```

As you can see the table tag is getting closed before the if statement

I am trying to get the output as

```
<h4 style='font-size:24px;padding:5px 0;margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#000;'>Order Details</h4>
<table style='border: 1px solid #ddd;width:100%;' cellpadding='6'><tr><td><strong>Apparel Color Selected:</strong> Black</td></tr>
<tr><td><strong>Adult Small:</strong> 20</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post your `getAdultQty()` function? It's probably a case of synchronous v.s. asynchronous requests. You likely need to add a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `innerHTML` is not a trivial operation, internally it's quite expensive and has side-effects, so only use `innerHTML` sparingly (I'm of the opinion `innerHTML` should have been defined as a function-property (e.g. `setInnerHTML(string)`) instead of a pseudo-value-property) - anyway...

Fortunately in your case it's easy to fix: use an intermediate variable instead:

```
var html = "<h4 style='font-size:24px;padding:5px 0;margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#000;'>Order Details</h4>";
html +="<table style='border: 1px solid #ddd;width:100%;' cellpadding='6'><tr><td><strong>Apparel Color Selected:</strong> "+ document.getElementById('colorselected').value + "</td></tr>";
if( getAdultQty().howmany_adult_s != 0 ) {
  html  +="<tr><td><strong>Adult Small:</strong> "+ getAdultQty().howmany_adult_s + "</td></tr>";  
}
html +="</table>";
qdetails.innerHTML = html;
```

You can improve this by using Template Literals ("backtick strings"):

```
var html = `
<h4 style="font-size:24px;padding:5px 0;margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#000;">Order Details</h4>
<table style='border: 1px solid #ddd;width:100%;' cellpadding='6'>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Apparel Color Selected:</strong> ${ document.getElementById('colorselected').value }</td>
    </tr>`;

if( getAdultQty().howmany_adult_s != 0 ) {
  html += `<tr><td><strong>Adult Small:</strong> ${ getAdultQty().howmany_adult_s }</td></tr>`;  
}
qdetails.innerHTML = html + `</table>`;
```

that said... your markup can be simplified by using stylesheets and the correct use of `<thead>` and `<th>`, which would make your HTML easier to read.

### About Template Literals

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

ECMAScript 6 introduced special string literals that are delimited with backticks (instead of quotes) which can contain raw line-breaks, and they contain embedded expressions with the `${ expr }` syntax as an alternative to string concatenation.

So this:

```
var fooTemplateLiteral = `My name is ${ name }
and I can span ${ 2 } lines!`;
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
var fooClassicString = "My name is " + name + "\
and I can span " + 2.toString() + " lines too, though with manual escapes.";
```

Comment: Thanks and I am open to learning can you provide me an example or some kind of reference how to define it as  function-property. Thanks again

Comment: @niceoneishere You can't, it's part of the DOM specification. That's just me complaining :)

Comment: Appreciate it for explaining in details and yes I will be adding classes just want to make sure everything works first before increasing the size of my stylesheet :) Thanks again